# Getting failures for C# email sending

Tags: c#, .net, email

This is the code that I have been making and I just tested to check whether it works but having an error message stating "System.FormatException"

I can't understand what I am having such problem. Please help

```
 public Mail(string sendMail)
    {
        this.sendAddress = new MailAddress(sendMail); // exception here
    }

    public void SetToAddress(string toMail)
    {
        this.toAddress = new MailAddress(toMail);
    }

    public string SendEmail(string subject, string body)
    {
        SmtpClient smtp = null;
        MailMessage message = null;
        try
        {
            smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(sendAddress.Address, sendPassword),
                Timeout = 20000
            };
            message = new MailMessage(sendAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body
            };
            smtp.Send(message);
            return "send mail ok";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "send mail fail";
        }
        finally
        {
            if (smtp != null) { smtp.Dispose(); }
            if (message != null) { message.Dispose(); }
        }
    }
}

namespace WindowsFormsApp12
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Mail mail = new Mail("email address type");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string toAddress = this.textBox2.Text;
            string subject = this.textBox1.Text;
            string body = this.textBox3.Text;
            if (toAddress == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("type in email address");
            }
            if (subject == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("type in email title");
            }
            if (body == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("type in email contents");
            }
            mail.SetToAddress(toAddress);
            MessageBox.Show(mail.SendEmail(subject, body));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the FormatException coming from?

Comment: public Mail(string sendMail)
            {
                this.sendAddress = new MailAddress(sendMail); <-here
            }

Comment: Then it's an invalid email address https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/591bk9e8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the .from part of mail.

```
mail = new MailMessage(sendAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
    From = new MailAddress("Blah@Blah.com;")
};
```

to addresses can be added like

```
 mail.To.Add("email@address.com");
```

Comment: I tried to insert From = "example@gmail.com" however as I put an email address after the = " there is red line marked showing an error. what should  I do?

Comment: Put comma after `Body = body` **,** @AJStudio

Comment: I have updated my solution. I would put a break point and check your to addresses also as I don't think they would be getting set

Comment: what would be the possible solution to overcome "System.FormatExpection" problem at the line of this.sendAddress = new MailAddress(sendMail);

Comment: I'm guessing your to email address is null. I don't think it is being set. Just set a test email address like above to see if it works, then work back from there

Answer (score 0):

FormatException for the constructor of MailAddress indicates an invalid email address. Source [MSDN documentation for MailAddress constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/591bk9e8(v=vs.110).aspx).